# Is there any way to package an app in Shoes?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

I am using the latest official release of shoes on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

I made a little test app but the packaging part of Shoes doesn't work apparently. I asked the support people for help but they said it's a known problem and it's not able to be done inside of the Shoes app.When they told me this, I tried the development version of Shoes4. I tried packaging one of the samples and it didn't work.

Has anybody been able to get the shoes packaging thing to work? Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packaging for shoes3 is sadly mostly broken (I think some command line options might work, but I do not know them). For shoes4 packaging is work in progress (and sometimes works) - it is scheduled for rc1 but right now we are still in pre alpha.

There are a few [open packaging bugs](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues?labels=packaging&page=1&state=open) - feel free to report your own so we can figure it out :-)